# Правильная сортировка массива на основе другого

Tags: php, массивы

```
$arr[] = ['первый',10,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['второй',5,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['третий',11,'бла'];

$sort = [5,11,10];
```

На выходе нам нужно получить `$arr` в том порядке, который указан в `$sort`. 
Сортируем по `$arr[][1]`. Т.е по второму значению в массиве `$arr`.

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться функцией пользовательской сортировки [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) с функцией поиска элементов в массиве [array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)

```
<?php

$arr[] = ['первый',10,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['второй',5,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['третий',11,'бла'];

$sort = [5,11,10];

usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    return array_search($a[1], $sort) - array_search($b[1], $sort);
});

var_dump($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kn7qg)

Можно оптимизировать сортировку, построив массив индексов предварительно:

```
$sort_map = array_flip($sort); // [5=>0, 11=>1, 10=>2]
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($sort_map) {
    return $sort_map[$a[1]] - $sort_map[$b[1]];
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5XHnH)

Comment: можно просто флип было, пройтись о исходному и в ключи вписать, без сортировки  вообще

Comment: это если гарантированно нет дубликатов/дырок

Comment: дырки-то не проблема (или я не понял, что за дырки:D ). а дубликаты да.

Comment: массив не будет нормализован при наличии дырок.. Например, json_encode породит объект вместо массива. да и вообще, массив `[1=>[], 0=>[], 2=>[]]` не всегда то, что нужно.

Comment: дак последующий array_values решит этот вопрос.

Comment: не решит: https://3v4l.org/86eAF

Comment: в смысле? в примере значения на своих местах, ключи от 0 в порядке возрастания.

Comment: **В смысле в смысле?** :) Если `пройтись по исходному и в ключи вписать`, то результирующий массив будет выглядеть как `[1=>[], 2=>[], 0=>[]]` *(если не создать массив из нужного числа элементов заранее)*

Comment: я, короче, про такой вариант: https://3v4l.org/BBOn0

Comment: Ну да, ты используешь массив нужной длины. Чего ответ-то не напишешь? И да, почему в этом варианте "дырки-то не проблема"?

Comment: видимо я не понял, про какие дырки речь идет :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr[]= ['первый',10,'бла'];
$arr[]= ['второй',5,'бла'];
$arr[]= ['третий',11,'бла'];

$sort = [5,11,10];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $key = array_search($item[1], $sort);
    $result[$key] = $item;    
}

ksort($result);
```

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) - осуществляет поиск данного значения в массиве и возвращает ключ первого найденного элемента в случае удачи.

Соответственно, идем циклом по исходному массиву, находим в массиве `$sort` значение из массива `$arr` на данной итерации и в результирующий массив `$result` под ключом, который вернул `array_search` кладем массив на данной итерации.

`ksort($result);` - для сортировки результирующего массива. Она отсортирует массив по ключам, сохраняя отношения между ключами и значениями

Comment: `array_values` в конце не помешал бы)

Comment: @vp_arth не понял где и для чего

Comment: Начальный массив является обычным массивом с последовательными числовыми индексами. А на выходе у вас ассоциативный массив с ключами 5/10/11

Comment: Хотя, скорее всего я неправ и sort не сохраняет индексы)) Но тогда и сортировка отработает некорректно. Нужен ksort+array_values.

Comment: @vp_arth я букву забыл просто .................`А на выходе у вас ассоциативный массив с ключами 5/10/11` - он не может получится таким на выходе..... потому что у меня ключ - индекс значения в массиве, а не само значение

Comment: допустим входной массив `[['',10],['',11],['',10]]`

Answer (score 1):

вариант для кучи - использование значений необходимого массива сортировки, как уже упорядоченных ключей для массива данных.

```
$sort = [5,11,10];

$data = array_flip($sort);
foreach($arr as $v){
    $data[$v[1]] = $v;
}
$data = array_values($data); // если нужна нумерация ключей с 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Без вспомогательных функций:

```
<?php

$arr[] = ['первый',10,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['второй',5,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['третий',11,'бла'];

$sort = [5,11,10];

for ($is = 0; $is < count($sort); $is++){
   for ($ia = 0; $ia < count($arr); $ia++){ 
        if ($arr[$ia][1] == $sort[$is]){
            $arr[count($arr)] = $arr[$is]; // запомнили затираемый элемент
            $arr[$is] = $arr[$ia]; // записали в новый индекс
            $arr[$ia] = $arr[count($arr) - 1]; // поменяли
            unset($arr[count($arr) - 1]); // удалили ненужный
        } 
   }
}

print_r($arr);

?>
```

[песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33a0fec97cbacf0c130557846c0b063545c87116)

и то же самое без затрат на работу с памятью:

```
<?php

$arr[] = ['первый',10,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['второй',5,'бла'];
$arr[] = ['третий',11,'бла'];

$sort = [5,11,10];

$tmp;

for ($is = 0; $is < count($sort); $is++){
   for ($ia = 0; $ia < count($arr); $ia++){ 
        if ($arr[$ia][1] == $sort[$is]){
            $tmp = $arr[$is]; // запомнили затираемый элемент
            $arr[$is] = $arr[$ia]; // записали в новый индекс
            $arr[$ia] = $tmp; // поменяли
        } 
   }
}

print_r($arr);

?>
```

[песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34055b166668b1a21e1c4c91d142818178e4e939)